# C# how to add 3 textboxes into 1 label

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, label

I am trying to add 3 textboxes into 1 label.

And not only that but first the combobox is going to add dear mr / dear miss then when i want to type in the textboxes it should come behind that.

This is the code I have been working with:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Man")
        lblAanhef.Text = "Geachte heer " + txtVnaam.Text +" "+ txtTvoegsel.Text  + " " + txtAnaam.Text;
    else
        lblAanhef.Text = "Geachte mevrouw"; 
}

private void fOpdracht1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1.Items.Add("Man");
    comboBox1.Items.Add("Vrouw");
}

private void txtVnaam_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

private void txtTvoegsel_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

private void txtAnaam_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

I have been struggling with this all morning but i cant seem to figure out how to do it.

If anyone knows please let me know.

Comment: What exctly doesn't work?

Comment: Question is not so clear. Can you be more specific on the problem

Comment: *add 3 textboxes into 1 label* - what exactly do you want to do? Do you mean you want to create a combobox?

Comment: @zephr Try this : `Label1.Text="Dear " + ComboBox1.SelectedItem + " "+Textbox1.text + " "+Textbox2.text + " " +Textbox3.text;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    changeText();
}

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    changeText();
}

private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    changeText();
}

private void changeText()
{
    if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Man")
        label1.Text = "Geachte heer " + textBox1.Text + " " + textBox2.Text;
    else
        label1.Text = "Geachte mevrouw " + textBox1.Text + " " + textBox2.Text;
}
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = "";
    comboBox1.Items.Add("Man");
    comboBox1.Items.Add("Woman");
    comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

Like this?

Comment: It's better to use formatting, not String concatenation: `label1.Text = String.Format("Geachte heer {0} {1} {2}", textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text)`

Comment: Is there a formal reason for this? I always seen concatenation as more clear to read

Comment: StringBuilder is better than both of them

Comment: String concatenation is relatively memory hungry (subject to the number of concatenations and length of elements being concatenated). `string.Format()` or `StringBuilder` class are usually (but not always) better.  Another overlooked option is `string.Join("", ...)` or `string.Join(" ", ...)`